# Password protect Chrome settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to create a rudimentary hiding of Chrome settings behind a password? I'm looking to prevent modification of extensions specifically. Not looking to password protect Chrome itself, just the settings page.

Comment: Not an answer but a possible start: [Set Chrome policies for users](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en), [How to Configure Google Chrome via Group Policies](http://woshub.com/how-to-configure-google-chrome-via-group-policies/), [Set Chrome policies for devices](http://woshub.com/how-to-configure-google-chrome-via-group-policies/). if all fails you can find a way to lock settings using a protected batch or a script. and then unlocking them using the same batch.

Comment: @MaherFattouh, would running the batch keep the settings permanently locked, or would I have to run it every time Chrome was launched?

Comment: the batch part is completely hypothetical, Ideally it'll only need to run once. have you looked into the "Set Chrome policies for users"? it seems like a reasonable solution with Chrome management and chrome admin. I'll try looking into it all deeper later tonight.

Comment: Here's some Ideas suggested by others: disable write access for the extensions folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` **OR** Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Google > Google Chrome. Look for a folder named Allowed extensions. There configure a blacklist of `*`